# Motion tracking error

Tags: tracking

I keep getting cant reconstruct error every time I solve, it keeps jumping from different scenes with that error.
When I first done a motion tracking before it was on the the clear, now its not. 
I have read about better shots and clearer and such, though the clips i can't redone do to the time I made it. These scenes are in the woods also.

How to fix it?

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Sorry just saw your question now. It was say "some data failed to reconstruct"

Comment: I saw the condole, the errors that was there had like track 1 error couldnt reconstruct no frame I took picture before but I couldnt upload was to big for the forum.

Comment: Try getting rid of the one track

Comment: I tried getting all the tracks that gave the error and that couldnt reconstruct.

Comment: Do you have 8 tracks on the keyframes?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I gave up on it. Went a different route. Dont something more simple and thinking now on my next thing to do other wise the fun will die for me.